# Parsing JSONArray of JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I am having a hard time parsing a JSONArray that looks like this:

```
{ 
  "informations": {
    "rows_nb": 4, //max is 4
    "report": [
      [ [ "BEACH", 59.35 ], [ "OCEAN", 40.65 ] ],//row1 , can be more than 2 arrays
      [ [ "OCEAN", 70.2  ], [ "BEACH", 29.8  ] ],//row2, can be more than 2 arrays
      [ "OCEAN", "BEACH" ],//row3
      [ "OCEAN" ]//row4
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried something like this, but didn't work :

```
JSONObject JSONresult = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject extras = JSONresult.getJSONObject("extras");
JSONArray report = extras.getJSONArray("report");
List<ArrayList<Object[]>> report_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object[]>>();
for (int i = 0; i < report.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray tmp = report.getJSONArray(i);
    ArrayList<Object[]> row = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for (int j = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++) {
        Object[] array = {tmp.getJSONArray(i).getString(0), tmp.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(1)};
        row.add(array);
    }
    report_list.add(row);
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the ObjectMapper you are using . Below is the sample for fasterxml.

```
String jsonInString = <your request>;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


//JSON from file to Object
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, YourClassName.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google gson](https://github.com/google/gson).
This would automatically convert your JSON to a Map of List of nested list's.

```
String json = "{report: [      [ [ BEACH, 59.35 ], [ OCEAN, 40.65 ] ],      [ [ OCEAN, 70.2  ], [ BEACH, 29.8  ] ],      [ OCEAN, BEACH],      [ OCEAN ]    ]}";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
```